Trying to make an indicator that plots a vertical line on the dips in price action
I'm trying to make an indicator that plots a vertical line on the dips in price action. And a future line based on the average of the distance between the past lines. I didn't get to the average part though in the code. Can't seem to get the lines to even plot on the dips.
here's what it's doing currently & the code:
Image 1
//
// inputs
cycle_length = input(20, title = "Cycle Length")

lowest = ta.lowestbars(low, cycle_length)
var count = 1
var low_found = 0.00
if lowest != low_found 
    count := count + 1
else
    lowest == lowest
    count := 1
//
highest = ta.highestbars(high, cycle_length)
var hcount = 1
var high_found = 0.00
if highest != high_found 
    hcount := hcount + 1
else
    highest == highest
    hcount := 1
//

Market_Cycle_label = line.new(x1 = (bar_index - count) + 1, y1 = high, x2 = (bar_index - count) + 1, y2 = low, extend = extend.both)

Here's what I'm trying to get it to do:
Image 2
I have tried the following aside from the code above..

Just plotting ta.lowest() with no counter or anything else



lowest = ta.lowest(low, cycle_length)
var count = 1
var low_found = 0.00
if lowest != low_found 
    count := count + 1
else
    lowest == lowest
    count := 1

Neither of these resulted in what I am attempting. It instead resulted similar to the first image above but with way more vertical line plots.
